# awk code to output lines with matching fields, but no output

Tags: awk, carriage-return

I'm trying to output lines in one file `fileB` that are matched with parameters in another file `fileA`, but my attempt doesn't output anything.

`fileA`:

```
chr1    7237    7238
chr1    7637    7637
chr1    7908    7908
chr1    8045    8045
chr1    8329    8329
chr1    8358    8358
chr1    8375    8375
chr1    8381    8381
```

`fileB`: (note that the fifth line has an extra column)

```
130 chr1    7237    7238    0k9imgkt
135 chr1    7637    7637    b9gko
138 chr1    7908    7908    kob9g
139 chr1    8045    8045    34e5rg  4r
151 chr1    8329    8329    b
151 chr1    8346    8346    345y46htyh
151 chr1    8346    8346    76jtuj
152 chr1    8358    8358    asfge
```

My code:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1,$2,$3];next}($2,$3,$4) in a{print $0}' fileA fileB
```

Expected output:

```
130 chr1    7237    7238    0k9imgkt
135 chr1    7637    7637    b9gko
138 chr1    7908    7908    kob9g
139 chr1    8045    8045    34e5rg  4r
151 chr1    8329    8329    b
152 chr1    8358    8358    asfge
```

Actual output:

Comment: GNU Awk 4.1.4, API: 1.1 (GNU MPFR 4.0.1, GNU MP 6.1.2)
Copyright (C) 1989, 1991-2016 Free Software Foundation.

Comment: Try `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1,$2,$3];next}($2,$3,$4) in a' fileA fileB | cat -v`. See any `^M`s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when input files have Windows line endings (i.e `\r\n`). Fix your input files using `dos2unix` tool and your command will work.

```sh
dos2unix fileA fileB
```

Or if you're using gawk or mawk, set record separator to `\r\n`:

```
awk -v RS='\r\n' ...
```

Comment: @DangIt yes I know, I just wanted to add it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

You can try with tr and grep :

```
< fileA tr -d '\r' | grep -f - fileB
```